# Update an Object by Matching with other Object Values depend on a Condition in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, object, properties

I have class as seen below

```
public class Channels
    {
        internal string CallerExt { get; set; }
        internal string ChannelName { get; set; }
        internal string CalleeExt { get; set; }

        public Channels(string CallerExt, string ChannelName, string CalleeExt)
        {
            this.CallerExt = CallerExt;
            this.ChannelName = ChannelName;
            this.CalleeExt = CalleeExt;
        }
    }
```

I want to add the list of Channel objects if there all the values are new, if `CallerExt`, and `CaleeExt` already exist in the same object then `ChannelName` should be updated with the new value for the same object?

I managed to find the object which contains `CallerExt` & `CalleeExt` Values matches with new values as seen below:

```
public static List<Channels> activeChannels = new List<Channels>();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(caller) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(now) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(callee))
{
    var recentChannel = activeChannels.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CallerExt == caller && c.CalleeExt == callee);
}
```

But I am not sure how to update that specific Object with the new Channel Name? Thanks for your help in advance..

Comment: Not exactly clear what you have problem with... I don't think "how to set property of an object" is what you are asking even if question reads exactly that way.

Comment: I meant a Value of an Object

Comment: `recentChannel.ChannelName = "new channel name";` Is that what you're asking

Comment: If CallerExt & CalleeExt values are matching with an existing Object then Channel Name should update the existing Channel Name of that specific object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for those who tried to answer my question following solution worked for me

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(caller) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(now) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(callee))
{
    var recentChannel = activeChannels.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CallerExt == caller && c.CalleeExt == callee);
    if (recentChannel != null)
        recentChannel.ChannelName = now;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rlDFZT)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var listOfChanels = new List<Channels>{ new Channels("1", "1", "1")};

        UpdateOrAdd(listOfChanels, new Channels("1", "2", "1"));
        UpdateOrAdd(listOfChanels, new Channels("2", "2", "2"));
        UpdateOrAdd(listOfChanels, new Channels("2", "3", "3"));

        foreach(var item in listOfChanels)
            Console.WriteLine(item.CalleeExt + item.CallerExt + item.ChannelName);
    }

    private static void UpdateOrAdd(List<Channels> list, Channels newObject)
    {
        var item = list.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CalleeExt == newObject.CalleeExt && p.CallerExt == newObject.CallerExt);

        if(item == null){
            list.Add(newObject);
        }else{
            item.ChannelName = newObject.ChannelName;
        }
    }

    public class Channels
    {
        internal string CallerExt { get; set; }
        internal string ChannelName { get; set; }
        internal string CalleeExt { get; set; }

        public Channels(string CallerExt, string ChannelName, string CalleeExt)
        {
            this.CallerExt = CallerExt;
            this.ChannelName = ChannelName;
            this.CalleeExt = CalleeExt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Mohamed Farook Mohamed Fazrin